# How can I resolve these C++ Compilation errors?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc, visual-leak-detector

I am trying to compile a Visual Studio solution. I believe the source files are OK. I have been getting a series of compilation errors.

Visual Studio newly Installed. 
I opened the solution and ran the build, it had errors. 
I went to Project, and noticed there were a number of missing features. 
I installed them: -

```
Windows XP Support for C++
Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015
Windows 8.1 SDK and Universal CRT SDK
Microsoft Foundation Classes for C++
```

Then I tried to build the solution but received an error informing me that

```
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'vld.h': No such file or directory ...
```

I researched this and managed to figure out this was referring to [Visual Leak Detector](https://vld.codeplex.com/)

I installed that. Now I am faced with fewer errors but hundreds of warnings. The warnings I'm not too concerned about for now. But I am trying to resolve the errors, to move things forward.

The errors I am getting now are:

> Firstly:-

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Suppression State
Error (active)      expected an identifier    c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\string 666 
Error (active)      expected an expression    c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\string 667 
Error (active)      expected a ';'            c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\string 689
```

In the string file (which has these errors) here is the portion of code that is causing the errors:

```
// basic_string LITERALS
inline namespace literals {
inline namespace string_literals {
inline string operator "" s(const char *_Str, size_t _Len)
    {   // construct literal from [_Str, _Str + _Len)
    return (string(_Str, _Len));
    }

inline wstring operator "" s(const wchar_t *_Str, size_t _Len)
    {   // construct literal from [_Str, _Str + _Len)
    return (wstring(_Str, _Len));
    }

inline u16string operator "" s(const char16_t *_Str, size_t _Len)
    {   // construct literal from [_Str, _Str + _Len)
    return (u16string(_Str, _Len));
    }

inline u32string operator "" s(const char32_t *_Str, size_t _Len)
    {   // construct literal from [_Str, _Str + _Len)
    return (u32string(_Str, _Len));
    }
}   // inline namespace string_literals
}   // inline namespace literals
_STD_END
```

The following 3 lines from the above are in error specifically according to the compiler: -

```
inline namespace literals {                    [line 666]
inline namespace string_literals {             [line 667]
_STD_END                                       [line 689]
```

However this is a Microsoft Include, straight from the Foundations Classes for C++ so I don't understand why it's generating this error.

> Secondly

I am receiving this error.

```
Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file 'C:\Git\projectpath\Release\aspirata.lib'    SymbolDumperUserDll C:\Git\projectpath\SymbolDumperUserDll\LINK 1
```

I've shortened the path name to 'project path' for simplicty above.

I have run out of ideas myself now having installed the three components I mentioned above, and VLD.

The final error is refererring to a .lib in the release directory, so I think this may be, something to do with a .lib file is not being created earlier in the compilation, maybe due to the first errors above? But i'm not too sure.

Can you suggest how I can overcome these compilation errors?

- Thanks

Comment: Somewhat upvoted this (thank you) then someone downvoted it. Exactly what do you think is wrong with this question, whoever downvoted it? Some people.

Comment: I don't think you provided enough info to be able to locate the source of the errors. It looks to me like there is some issue above the line that includes the string header.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianRoman can you suggest how I could track down any further information that would help to troubleshoot this? I've been looking at the compilation errors for about 12 hours now. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: @llnspectable it might surprise you but i don't actually sit around thinking of questions that could help the programming world and then post them. My question relates to an individual need. I have worded it eloquently. It is well presented. All the information within my degree of expertise I am able to offer I have offered. Seriously, you really need to go find something more productive to do with your time, than invent faults with questions, that then 'grants' you the scope to criticise them. - and by the way the 'two' questions, are no doubt related.

Comment: I guess you have downloaded this project from the internet and you are missing several dependencies. You sholud look for a file or section in documentation explaning what you have to do to compile and run this project. If you are recieving erorrs in MFC library files then downloading update packages for VS2015 is never a bad idea.

Comment: There are different packages for supporting Windows XP. If your project settings for Platform Toolset is `Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)` , that version doesn't support inline namespaces. It must be v140 (Visual Studio 2015).

Comment: Thanks @BoPersson that sounds promising, I was puzzled why I was getting errors from MFC files. Will investigate it. Many thanks

Comment: *"How can I resolve these C++ Compilation errors?"* as a title does not fit the *"is well presented"* category, I'm afraid.